# mysql select issue, multi tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Whilst I've asked a question similar to this before, I've attempted to apply the same technique to it and its just not working as it should and erroring and various points.

I've created an sqlfiddle for this; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1a29

I'm attempting to create a select function that will return the animal_id, animal_name,animal_type_name, shelter_name, animal_type_id and location_name.

I've attempted to have a good at it with the following code but clearly I'm missing something;

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT animal_id, animal_name, animal_type_name, shelter_name, shop_id, location_name
                                FROM animals a
                                INNER JOIN shelter s ON s.shop_id = a.shop_id
                                INNER JOIN location l ON l.location_id = s.location_id
                                INNER JOIN animal_types at ON at.animal_type_id = a.animal_type_id');
```

Comment: with use of inner join each table MUST contain a coorsponding value.  Are you sure all animals have shelters and locations and types?

Comment: You were close: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1a29/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are selecting the column name which is ambiguous or which exists on multiple tables. In this case it's the `shop_id`. In order to execute the query well, you need to specify where the column `shop_id` should come from,

```
SELECT animal_id, animal_name, animal_type_name, 
       shelter_name, s.shop_id, location_name
FROM animals a
INNER JOIN shelter s ON s.shop_id = a.shop_id
INNER JOIN location l ON l.location_id = s.location_id
INNER JOIN animal_types at ON at.animal_type_id = a.animal_type_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1a29/2)

Comment: Thank you JW! A quick google search told me that it was because it was listed twice but the example appears to put "tablename.collum" so when i tired to do shelter.shop_id, it errored. It now makes sense, thanks once again!

Comment: how are your tables related with each other?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, it generate error:

> Column 'shop_id' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT animal_id,
>   animal_name, animal_type_name, shelter_name, shop_id, location_name
>   FROM animals a INNER JOIN shelter s ON s.shop_id = a.shop_id INNER
>   JOIN location l ON l.location_id = s.location_id INNER JOIN
>   animal_types at ON at.animal_type_id = a.animal_type_id

From the error: your `shop_id` column belongs to more one table, so you must qualified it with table name / table alias.

Change your query to this :

```
SELECT animal_id, animal_name, animal_type_name, shelter_name, s.shop_id, location_name
                                FROM animals a
                                INNER JOIN shelter s ON s.shop_id = a.shop_id
                                INNER JOIN location l ON l.location_id = s.location_id
                                INNER JOIN animal_types at ON at.animal_type_id = a.animal_type_id
```